# How can we benchmark performance of Qt Wayland on a hardware platform?

Tags: opengl, benchmarking, wayland, qtwayland

How can we benchmark performance of Qt Wayland on a hardware platform?
Do we have any benchmarking tools like "glmark2-es2" which is used for standard OpenGL benchmarking. This is required to see if we can use Qt Wayland compositor or have to use Wayland.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Chekout [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions on SO

Comment: I assume you meant "Weston" and not "Wayland" in your last sentence?

Comment: @Riyaz, I want to benchmark performance of Qt Wayland compositor against a standard Wayland/Weston compositor based on which I want to make a choice of the compositor we would use. The question I have is are there any standard tools available to benchmark Qt Wayland performance? E.g. if I have to benchmark graphics performance I can use glmark2-es2 standard benchmarking tool, do we have similar tools for benchmarking QtWayland?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glmark2` works on Wayland as well, however it is not in it's current condition a good measure of actual performance. It tries to render frames as fast as possible, regardless of how fast the compositor is actually able to show them. This means most of the frames are wasted, and never shown on the screen. So what it usually measures is how good the compositor is at ignoring superfluous frames from a misbehaving client (most clients wait for the compositor to tell them to draw a new frame so it can be close to vsync). Actually, a compositor locked at a ridiculously low frame rate can  more easily achieve a high glmark2 score than one running at a steady 60fps.

Instead, it's better to use a tool that tries to increase the workload per frame while keeping the frame-rate constant at 60fps.

If you're using Qt anyway, then one such tool is https://github.com/CrimsonAS/qmlbench. You'll probably be able to find others if you want something toolkit independent.

EDIT: If you want more of my rants about why `glmark2-es` is a horrible tool to benchmark compositors, see http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/05/31/qt-wayland-summary/#comment-1200024

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so I understand that glmark2-es2 is not a good way to benchmark. My use case is to have a compositor which can be used to render multiple 4K videos ( rendered simultaneously) in a Desktop environment at 60FPS. I would like to confirm if this use case can be supported by QtWayland.  I have little experience with QtWayland compositor  but seems a simple interface to use. I would like to know if QMLbench or any other benchmarking tool can help me to conclude if this performance can be achieved using QtWayland compostor.

Comment: I tried with qmlbench. First I run the qwindow-compositor example application in the qtwayland, the I tried to to run the qmlbench tool using the following commad "$ ./src/qmlbench  /home/test/Downloads/qmlbench-master/benchmarks/auto/ani
mations/comparison/". Now the qmlbench toolis working. if I export the variable QT_QPA_PLATFORM="wayland",then if I run the same command it shows as Failed to determine what client buffer integration to use, failed to acquire GL context to get version info, Using the 'wl-shell' shell integration Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat

Comment: Do normal Qt applications work? And how are you running the compositor? On what QPA platform? And what kind of graphics stack are you running? Might be a good idea to open a separate question.